# Changing Ansible dynamic inventory order based on target group health check status

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, ansible, devops, amazon-elb

I'm trying to set up rolling deployments on a AWS EC2 2-node cluster behind an ALB via Ansible. The rough process goes like this for each node in serial —

```
+----------+   +----------+   +----------+
|Remove app|   |Redeploy  |   |Add back  |
|from load |-->|new app   |-->|to load   |
|balancer  |   |          |   |balancer  |
+----------+   +----------+   +----------+
```

I use Ansible dynamic inventory to select my nodes, and they're sorted by IP address by default. Now consider these 4 scenarios right before deployment —

1. Both nodes are healthy.
2. Node #1 is unhealthy and node #2 is healthy.
3. Node #1 is healthy and node #2 is unhealthy.
4. Both nodes are unhealthy.

Now under scenario #3, I'd end up removing the only healthy node. How do I avoid this?

Comment: How do you know which ones are healthy?  Are you assuming that they will be healthy after redeploying the new app?

Comment: I am, yes. During deployments I wait for their health check status to turn `healthy`.

Answer (score 0):

either add a step to your playbook that performs a sanity check that doesn't permit you to remove a node from the loadbalancer if the remaining number of healthy nodes would be less than one

or

work out how to preferentially remove unhealthy nodes from the load balancer first.  Can you split the nodes into groups by their health-check status, then process unhealthy nodes first?  Or alternately change the sort order so that it's by health check status rather than by ip address?

As an alternate methodology - can you not add new nodes before removing old ones?

Comment: This is where I’m stuck. For me to sort the inventory by target group health status, I’d have to write my own inventory plugin. I’m trying to see if there’s another method I could use to achieve the same result.

Comment: Adding new nodes before removing old ones is an approach I’ll fall back on if I can’t solve my original problem.

Answer (score 0):

OK, since you have a `healthy` flag, use it to inculde an `update` role:

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
  - include_role:
      role: update
    when: not healthy
  - include_role:
      role: update
    when: healthy
```

This way, the unhealthy ones are done first.

Comment: Healthy is just the ALB target group listener’s health status, not tags. I’m having trouble understanding how this solves my problem — the same role is included twice.

Comment: The `healthy` flag here is not a tag, but a variable associated with each individual host you are working on.  Yes, the same role is included twice.  The first time it runs only on those hosts whose `healthy` flag is FALSE, and the second time it runs only on those hosts whose `healthy` flag is TRUE.